Почему тема числительных вызывает так много трудностей у носителей русского языка
Это мы видим по недавней теме
Вопрос несложный, предложение самое обычное. Но даже те отвечающие, которые знают правильное решение, не могу четко, коротко и понятно объяснить это другим.

Ответ короткий:  Это очень сложная по грамматике тема. Эта тема недостаточно изучается в школе.
Заданный вопрос: Скажите, как правильно: 32 обучающихся или 32 обучающегося? Правильно ли составлена фраза "перевести 31 обучающегося в 5 класс"?
ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ
Что надо знать о числительных?
Числительные оформились в отдельную часть речи позже других слов, и состав числительных очень разный по грамматике. Интересно то, что  у большинства количественных числительных нет грамматических категорий рода и числа.
Существует основное правило для числительных, которое обозначено в числовых сочетаниях.  Это особая статья: перед нами числовой оборот как оборотень. В начальной форме числительное (главное слово) задает Р.п существительному (пять столов), а в остальных формах  числительное (зависимое  слово) согласуется с существительным (пятью столами).
Есть проблемные числительные, которые нарушают общий порядок согласования.  Это один и два, три, четыре.   Они и сами по себе нестандартны (один стол, два стола, пять столов), да еще входят в составные числительные (тридцать один стол, тридцать два стола, тридцать пять столов).
Числительное один тоже со своим характером: в косвенных падежах его фактически можно приравнять к прилагательному, ведь категория числа и даже род у него есть (одним столом, одними столами). В начальной же форме  у него окончание  существительного  (один стол, одна кровать).  Статус у слова особый: оно категорически не приемлет стоящих рядом и не согласованных с ним слов: двадцать один студент пришел, а не пришли.
В числовых оборотах  используются  определения, как и в обычных сочетаниях: тридцать один одинаковый стол, тридцать два одинаковых стола, тридцать пять одинаковых столов. Здесь для определений  мы видим форму мн. числа для всех числительных, кроме  «один».
О категории одушевленности для СОСТАВНЫХ числительных: Розенталь  §153.  Пункт 4. При литературной форме доставить двадцать два пассажира (в конструкциях с составными числительными, оканчивающимися на два, три, четыре, винительный падеж сохраняет форму именительного независимо от категории одушевленности) существует разговорная форма доставить двадцать двух пассажиров.
И вот все это надо знать, чтобы записать простейшее предложение?  Что за язык,  разве можно все это выучить, запомнить?!  Но грамматику не учат, ее просто понимают и знают. За 11 лет обучения в школе можно было бы постепенно освоить…
Но есть и нечто хорошее.  Фразеология числительных запоминается на интуитивном уровне: надо читать, слушать правильную речь, изучать и хорошо знать базовые модели с числительными.
РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ
Скажите, как правильно: 32 обучающихся или 32 обучающегося? Правильно ли составлена фраза "перевести 31 обучающегося в 5 класс"?
Анализ:
 Проблемные числительные:  один и два. 
 Субстантивированное прилагательное (в значении 
 (сущ.).  Оно у нас на  правах именно 
 прилагательного,  а не существительного.  Об этом 
 особо упоминается в Грамматике-80;
 Падеж винительный, должна быть форма Р.п. (для 
 одуш. сущ.). Но для составных числительных 
 сохраняется форма В.п.

Как решить?   Проще всего использовать знакомые формы.
(1) Правильно: тридцать один ученик, тридцать два ученика. Перевести тридцать одного ученика в пятый класс. Перевести тридцать два ученика в пятый класс.
(2) Потом добавляем определение обучающийся:
Правильно: тридцать один обучающийся ученик, тридцать два обучающихся ученика. Перевести тридцать одного обучающегося ученика в пятый класс. Перевести тридцать два  обучающихся ученика в пятый класс.
(3) А теперь убираем лишнее существительное:
Правильно: тридцать один обучающийся, тридцать два обучающихся. Перевести тридцать одного обучающегося в пятый класс. Перевести тридцать два  обучающихся в пятый класс.
ВЫВОД
Вот так все просто!  Казалось бы!  Вот умора! Литературное согласование "перевести тридцать два  обучающихся ученика" — это шедевр! Рекомендуется для особо одаренных. Но Розенталь так велит.
В любом случае, не стоит заучивать правила в правописании числительных, а потом дословно цитировать их при ответе! Трудно понимается такое многословие. Но надо знать основы грамматики, и лучше всего отрабатывать эти знания на простых базовых примерах.
P. S. При цифровой записи правильные падежные формы числительных не увидишь.  Удобно!

Sharon: «Правильно: …Перевести тридцать двух учеников в пятый класс. Здесь-то мы не ошибемся! ===  «Счастлив, кто верует…» По-моему, более правильным вариантом считается всё же такой: «Перевести тридцать два ученика в пятый класс»

Да, забавно,) хорошо, что нашли ошибку. Я, кстати, сначала написал 32-а, потом подумал, зачем тут окончание у тридцать двА) и убрал, когда вы написали ответ тридцать двух, даже внимания не обратил)

@Буратино  А вы цифрами пишите, как другие делают: перевести 32 обучающихся. Пусть читают как хотят И тогда уже не будет ни загадок, ни ошибок... ))  // Все дело в том, что категория одушевленности есть только у некоторых числительных, в частности ее нет у составных числительных. Перевели тридцать учеников, двух учеников, но тридцать два ученика. // Кстати, тридцать двух учеников - это не ошибка, а разговорная форма по Розенталю.

@Буратино Перевести двух обучающихся, но перевести тридцать два обучающихся.  Нормальный человек сказал бы:  перевести тридцать двух обучающихся.  Надо бы откорректировать дополнительно СТИЛИСТИКУ, устарела уже))  Как у Грибоедова: На них он выменял борзые три собаки!  Розенталь:  3.      В вариантах купить двух коров – купить две коровы, подстрелить трех уток – подстрелить три утки (при названиях животных в форме женского рода, когда речь идет об общем счете, купле-продаже) вторая форма имеет разговорный характер.

А вот числительному один все нипочем. Входит в составное числительное, а форма Р.п. Отчего так? Давайте напишем: перевести тридцать один ученик (В.п.).
